# How to access data in bidirectional many to many mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

UserDetail.java (model class)

```
@Entity
public class UserDetail {

    @Id
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> role;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "user")
    private List<GroupDetail> group;

}
```

GroupDetail.java ( model class)

```
@Entity
public class GroupDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String groupName;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<UserDetail> user;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> role;
}
```

Here as you can see GroupDetail is the owner of the association and Hibernate will only check that side when maintaining the association.

So, how do i get List of GroupDetail using the user email?

Answer (score 0):

Following should work for you:

`select userDtl.group from UserDetail userDtl where userDtl.email = 'Your Email'`

If this does not work, then you could try to use join explicitly like this:

`select g from UserDetail u join u.group g where u.email = 'Your Email'`

Comment: how to extract using java? (Mapping table is GroupDetail_UserDetail )

Comment: @ParthPahariya, this is the HQL query, that you can run in Java. ALso, your entity tables seems to be missing the mapping table(GroupDetail_UserDetail )

Comment: the mapping table(GroupDetail_UserDetail )  is created by hibernate automatically in database table

Answer (score 0):

Do this, add getter and setter in both entities.

```
UserDetails user = em.find(UserDetails.class, emailId);
 List<GroupDetail> group = user.getGroup();
```

Comment: what is this "em"?

Comment: em is EntityManager.If you are using JPA then use em. Using hibernate then use session.get(UserDetails.class, emailId);